# Another datePicker minDate issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Sorry, I've looked through most of the posts that relate to this issue, but I just can't seem to get this working

I have a form with a number of radio buttons:

```
<input class="type" type="radio" name="type" data-id="10">Don't let user select less than 10 business days
<input class="type" type="radio" name="type" data-id="5">Don't let user select less than 5 business days
```

User picks the first radio button, the calendar should not allow them to select a date less than 10 days from now

User picks the second radio button, the calendar should not allow them to select a date less than 5 days from now

(This is part of a huge form, so I've just included a subset of the code.  Thanks so much for taking a look, I've been at this all day!!)

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({   
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,               
    duration:"fast",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    gotoCurrent:false,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    constrainInput: true,
    maxDate: "+6M", 
    shortYearCutoff: "+10"

  });
$(".type").click(function() {
daysAdd = $(this).attr('data-id');  
$("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", daysAdd);
});
```

Comment: What is not working? http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TRnnG/ works fine for me... I suspect that there must be some issue in noWeekendsOrHolidays function.

Comment: You're right, it IS working in jsfiddle (even with the nWeekendsOrHolidays).  Let me take another look on my end.  Sorry for not checking in jsfiddle before I posted.  I've never used before!! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.. jsFiddle is a nice place to test these case to narrow down the issue. I am just going to post the same comment as an answer for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is works fine for me. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TRnnG)

I suspect that there must be some issue in noWeekendsOrHolidays function.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
$(".type").click(function() {
   daysAdd = $(this).attr('data-id');
   var modifiedDate = new Date();
   modifiedDate.setDate(Number(modifiedDate.getDate())+Number(daysAdd));
   $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "minDate", modifiedDate);
});
```

Comment: The OP code is working fine as is http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TRnnG/ Except for the noWeekendsOrHolidays function which is not provided in the post.